# Create proxy solution using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, reverse-proxy

I have a case where I want to remove cookie in the request and send the request to another server and display response to the end user.

Example:

`client -> x.website.com -> remove cookie -> y.website.com`

Current solution:

`client -> x.website.com -> ec2 instance, nginx proxy, remove cookie -> y.website.com`

I want to remove ec2 instance in the middle as it's expensive.

Is any way I can achieve using AWS Resources?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to address your use case recommended in order.

1. Using [AWS CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) as a proxy where you can you can add the y.website.com as a origin and also configure not to [forward the cookies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Cookies.html).
2. Using [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) & [Mapping templates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) to only map other headers excluding cookie header, and proxy the y.website.com.
3. Using API Gateway and [Lambda Proxy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html) where you need to write a code to exclude the header and forward the request to y.website.com.

Comment: It seems to be CloudFront best to my problem. Thanks

Comment: what if i want to edit the response before sending it back to client, for example i have s3 webserver contains a lot of static pages and i want to serve these pages with a small script injection(in the <body/>) for each request

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to implement something already?

That may work:

```
[Request]
client -> API Gateway -> AWS Lambda(Forward the Request) -> y.website.com

[Response]
client <- API Gateway <- AWS Lambda(Response) <- y.website.com
```

https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/details

https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/details

Comment: I have not tried lambda. I will try to solve it by lambda. Do you have any sample script, that can be used?